# How to get dynamically created anchor tags to redirect to action method

Tags: jquery, html, model-view-controller

I have added click events to dynamically created anchors. The html renders correctly, and I am hitting the Jquery event function. However the action method on the server is never hit.

I have searched for 'Dynamically Created Anchors not firing events'. I have tried what I could understand. The events are being hit but I do not know why the urls are not redirecting to the action methods. Jquery is rather new to me.

My JQuery for creating the anchors and adding events based off the anchor's class:

```
function BuildContent(data, contentarea) {
    contentarea.empty();
    //Build Data Rows
    $.each(data.users, function () {
        contentarea.append(
            "<tr>" +
            "<td data-title='Last Name'>" + this.lastName + "</td>" +
            "<td data-title='First Name'>" + this.firstName + "</td>" +
            "<td data-title='Company Name'>" + this.companyName + "</td>" +
            "<td data-title='Action'> <a class='edituser' ID='" + this.id + "'" +
            " asp-controller='Test' asp-action='EditUser' asp-route-id='" + this.id + "'>Edit</a> </td>" +
            "</tr>"
        );
    });
    contentarea.show();
    // Add click event to anchors
    $(".edituser").on("click", function (e) {
        alert(this.getAttribute('id'));
     });
}
```

Here is what gets rendered on the page, which I think is correct:

```
<td data-title="Action"> <a class="edituser" id="d58b6399-f284-4fea-b350-73a0bf53a1bd" asp-controller="Test" asp-action="EditUser" asp-route-id="d58b6399-f284-4fea-b350-73a0bf53a1bd">Edit</a> </td>
```

And here is what the browser page shows(I clicked on a different user):

```
<td data-title='Action'>
    <a href="/Test/EditUser/942fb374-cc46-4805-93cf-398cbc9d82af">Edit</a>
</td>
```

I just need the anchors to jump back to the action in the controller and pass the Id as a parameter. But again, the action method on the server never gets hit. There are no error messages. And the problem only occurs with the Dynamically created HTML anchors.

Comment: which one is working ?

Comment: Any anchor I use on the page, such as the menu items, the column header that I use to sort with, really any that are statically coded work. I statically added 5 anchors for the first 5 records, they worked.

Comment: <a href="/Test/EditUser/942fb374-cc46-4805-93cf-398cbc9d82af">Edit</a> is this wokring??

Comment: Ah you are a genius, maybe, lol. There is something different about the elements when I inspect them. The Page Source looks correct, but the elements have the asp tags still on them.

Comment: so am i. ;) but you could directly check by calling url from browser. like "YourSitePath/Test/EditUser/942fb374-cc46-4805-93cf-398cbc9d82af" so you can be sure if method is working or not.

Comment: actually, thanks to your question, I did. but I do not know why the Element shows the asp help tags, but the page source give a clickable link that actually works. It seems to me I can't use asp tags in the code that I am building?

Comment: cant you render directly anchor tag with href??

Comment: like <a class='edituser'  href='/Test/EditUser/" + this.id + "'>Edit</a>

Comment: Yes, that worked. How do I like your comments? New to SO as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will help you.

```
function BuildContent(data, contentarea) {
    contentarea.empty();
    //Build Data Rows
    $.each(data.users, function () {
        contentarea.append(
            "<tr>" +
            "<td data-title='Last Name'>" + this.lastName + "</td>" +
            "<td data-title='First Name'>" + this.firstName + "</td>" +
            "<td data-title='Company Name'>" + this.companyName + "</td>" +
            "<td data-title='Action'>  <a class='edituser' href='/Test/EditUser/" + this.id + "'>Edit</a> </td>" +
            "</tr>"
        );
    });
    contentarea.show();
    // Add click event to anchors
    $(".edituser").on("click", function (e) {
        alert(this.getAttribute('id'));
     });
}
```